# What reason do I have to equip an ammo pack in my utility slot?

Tags: planetside-2

Engineers start the game with ammunition packs in their utility slot (<kbd>4</kbd>), and can unlock tank mines or anti-personnel mines to equip in that slot instead.

However, regardless of what is equipped in your utility slot, you can always drop ammo packs by switching to your nano-construction tool (<kbd>5</kbd>) and pressing the Fire Mode key (<kbd>B</kbd> by default).

Other than the fact that you have to spend certs to unlock mines, what's the point of equipping an ammo pack in the utility slot at all? Is the ammo pack in your utility slot somehow different from the packs your construction tool create, or are they completely redundant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The separate ammunition pack is identical to the one from the nano-construction tool, but it is quicker and easier to deploy, as it requires fewer actions. It is also unaffected by the nano-tool's cooldown.

[Source](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Engineer)

Comment: Seems like it's definitely not worth equipping then, considering the nano-tool's cooldown is only a few seconds and you'd give up the ability to carry mines.

Comment: As of the latest patch it is no longer possible to access the ammo box using the nano-construction tool. Ammo boxes are deployed using the "class ability" button.